# ASP.NET LoginUser.DestinationPageUrl not working properly

Tags: asp.net, login-control

The  HTML is like:

```
  <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false" OnLoggedIn="LoginUser_LoggedIn"
                    OnLoginError="LoginUser_LoginError">
</asp:Login>
```

On `LoginUser_LoggedIn` event I am setting the destination URL like:

```
LoginUser.DestinationPageUrl = "~/mycustompage.aspx";
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginUser.UserName, true);
```

Here when there is NO `ReturnUrl` in page URL then it is redirecting to "~/mycustompage.aspx" page but if there is any ReturnUrl specified in the URL then it is redirecting to the ReturnUrl page.

I always want to redirect to "~/mycustompage.aspx" page whether ReturnUrl is there or not. How to achieve this?

Many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DestinationPageUrl` is the default destination page after Login.

`?ReturnUrl` is stronger than `DestinationPageUrl` so, if it is set it wins.

`Response.Redirect` in `LoginUser_LoggedIn` is stronger than `ReturnUrl` so, if you want to override `ReturnUrl`  you must use this code:

```
 void LoginUser_LoggedIn(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Response.Redirect("~/mycustompage.aspx");
      ....
    }
```

---

`DestinationPageUrl` should be set in the aspx page

```
 <asp:Login DestinationPageUrl="~/mycustompage.aspx" ... />
```

or in  `Page_Load` event to work properly.

```
void PageLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      LoginUser.DestinationPageUrl = "~/mycustompage.aspx";
      ....
    }
```

If you must change the destination page after login (in example if the page changes depending on the user or the user's role) you must use `Server.trasfer()` ore `Response.Redirect()`.

```
void LoginUser_LoggedIn(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Response.Redirect("~/mycustompage.aspx");
      ....
    }
```

Comment: No, it is not working for me :(. I have set the DestinationPageUrl = "~/mycustompage.aspx" page in .aspx page and in LoginUser_LoggedIn event I'm redirecting to "~/mycustompage.aspx" page. It is failing for RedirectUrl like `http://www.example.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/secret/search.aspx`.

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm. I did a mistake by `false` as second parameter in Response.Redirect("~/mycustompage.aspx", false). I changed it to Response.Redirect("~/mycustompage.aspx") and it worked. Thank you very much Emanuele :)